# flash movie stops after a while?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

im a newbie to flash,and i hav got this really weird problem.i have created a movie that has got 15 scenes,it stops working on the 15th scene.is there any reason why this is happening?

has anyone come across a similar problem? i know this might be the lamest question some one has ever asked about flash on this site?

if i hav done some thing stupid,please excuse my ignorance.

thanks

Comment: i have created this using flash cs4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your time-line. Do you have it set to show all 15 scenes? Or is there a stop command in the 14th frame?

Take a look at the timeline tutorial:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7f84a.html

Comment: sorry m8,it actually stops on the 15th scene...how do i set the timleine to show all the scenes i create.is this something in the preferences>